# disabling the Validation in struts2 and use my own customized validation

Tags: validation, struts2

I'm developing web project in struts2 and I want validation in my own customized validation by disabling the struts2 validation, because if one field is being sent back it will check all fields but I want to check only at the time of submit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully get the idea, but there's a thing called `@SkipValidation` you can annotate methods with.